# HTML Javascript: pass checked box value to .js function correctly but webpage doesn't display data

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, d3.js

I want to pass a checked value (upon hitting the submit button) to the .js function. The .js function should then take that checked value and query data from a sqlite db and AWS to populate the current webpage.

Here is what I think is happening in the posted code below. After checking a single box and hitting submit, the checked value is being passed to function **getQuestionData()**. Within **getQuestionData()**, an endpoint is created using the passed value then function **appendInnerHTML** is called to populate the page with queried data.

The error I get is

> unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]

applied to the 4th line from the bottom ---- *q.append('img')*.

I also noticed that whichever box is checked, my local URL changes. For example, if the box with Coordinate Geometry is checked, the url changes to

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/?topic=Coordinate+Geometry

I had some help setting this up so I'm not 100% clear on the fundamentals, if that wasn't already obvious..

**CODE**

HTML

```
<form id="checkboxes">
    <input type="submit" id="submitTopic" onsubmit="getQuestionData(this.value)">
</form>
```

.js

```
function getQuestionData() {

    sampleValue = $('input[id=submitTopic]:checked').val()
    //document.getElementById("submitTopic").value;

    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("solve").innerHTML = ""

    var endPointQuestionData = '/api/v1/questions/' + sampleValue
    Plotly.d3.json(endPointQuestionData, function(error, response) {

        if (error) return console.warn(error);

        appendInnerHMTL(response)
    });
};



//populates webpage with data from sqlite db
function appendInnerHMTL(response) {

    d3.select("#solve")
        .append('h2')
        .text("Solve.")

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){

            q = d3.select("#question")
                  d =  q.append('div')
                  .append('strong')
                  .text(response[i]['id'])
                  d.append('div')
                       button = d.append('input')
                           .attr('class','button')
                           .attr('type','button')
                           .attr('value','Show Answer')
                           .attr('onclick','showAnswer('+ i + ')')
                       shownAnswer = d.append('div')
                           .attr('class','shownAnswer')
                           .text(response[i]['ans'])
                           document.getElementsByClassName('shownAnswer')[i].style.display='none';

            //appends image from Amazon AWS to each id
            q.append('img')
                .attr('src', 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/actmath/' + response[i]['date'] + '/' + response[i]['id'] + '.JPG')
                //retrieve .jpg file if .JPG file not found
                .attr('onerror', 'this.oneerror=null;this.src=\"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/actmath/' + response[i]['date'] + '/' + response[i]['id'] + '.jpg\";')



      }
```

};

Comment: Check this out - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Shoot. I should change the title because I'm able to pass the value correctly (your link is spot on) but I'm not sure why my code is not working. It won't display the data that is queried from the sqlite db and Amazon AWS.